# Write a function that filters a dataset for rows that contains all of the words in a list of words

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I want to get a sub-dataframe that contains all elements in a list.
Let's take the DataFrame as an example.

```
my_dict = {
    'Job': ['Painting', 'Capentry', 'Teacher', 'Farming'],
    'Job_Detail': ['all sort of painting', 
                  'kitchen utensils, all types of roofing etc.',\
                  'skill and practical oriented teaching',\
                  'all agricultural practices']
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
```

Output looks thus:

```
    Job         Job_Detail
0   Painting    all sort of painting
1   Capentry    kitchen utensils, all types of roofing etc.
2   Teacher     skill and practical oriented teaching
3   Farming     all agricultural practices
```

`my_lst = ['of', 'all']`

I want to filter `df` with `mylst` to get a sub_DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    Job         Job_Detail
0   Painting    all sort of painting
1   Capentry    kitchen utensils, all types of roofing etc.
```

I've tried `df[df.Job_Detail.isin(['of', 'all'])` but it returns an empty DataFrame.

Comment: Shouldn't your function also return `3   Farming     all agricultural practices`, since it has 'all' in it too?

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't. All elements in ```my_lst``` should be in the row of ```Job_Detail```.

Comment: Ok, it seems that `and` is bit more tricky than `or` . I think I have a solution, though.

Comment: I edited my solution to include code that only selects rows with both 'of' and 'all'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lone Your code answered a different question, but it helped me arrive at the answer. Thank you, appreciated.

Here's the closest to what I needed:

`df[(df.Job_Detail.str.contains('of')) & (df.Job_Detail.str.contains('all'))]`

Comment: My second answer should do the same thing as your code, but uses `my_lst` as the list of strings to search for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no pandas expert, but the best function to use here seems to be [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains)

From the docs:

> Series.str.contains(pat, case=True, flags=0, na=None, regex=True)
>
> Test if pattern or regex is contained within a string of a Series or Index.
>
> Return boolean Series or Index based on whether a given pattern or regex is contained within a string of a Series or Index.

## Edit: This masks using `or`, not `and`

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {
    'Job': ['Painting', 'Capentry', 'Teacher', 'Farming'],
    'Job_Detail': ['all sort of painting', 
                  'kitchen utensils, all types of roofing etc.',
                  'skill and practical oriented teaching',
                  'all agricultural practices']
          }

my_lst = ['of', 'all']

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

print(df)


mask = df.Job_Detail.str.contains('|'.join(my_lst), regex=True)

print(df[mask])
```

## Here's a solution that masks uing `and`:

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {
    'Job': ['Painting', 'Capentry', 'Teacher', 'Farming'],
    'Job_Detail': ['all sort of painting', 
                  'kitchen utensils, all types of roofing etc.',
                  'skill and practical oriented teaching',
                  'all agricultural practices']
          }

my_lst = ['of', 'all']

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

print(df)

print("------")

masks = [df.Job_Detail.str.contains(word) for word in my_lst]
mask = pd.concat(masks, axis=1).all(axis=1)


print(df[mask])
```